# Get spring bean from application context in groovy class

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy

I'm converting a grails application to spring. How to get a spring bean in a groovy or java class from spring **'WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml'**.

This was the code I used for grails application

```
queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory)Holders.applicationContext.getBean("jmsConnectionFactory");
```

I've tried

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
queueConnectionFactory usa = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.getBean("jmsConnectionFactory");
```

but it didn't work , I was getting an error

java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)

Please help me to resolve this issue . Thanks

Comment: Is your `applicationContext.xml` file located on the classpath?  If it is within the root of `WEB-INF` I do not believe it is.  Try moving it to the root of a source folder.

Comment: it is under 'main/webapps/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml' directory. So it should available right?

Comment: I'll definitely try that . Btw the code I used to get bean is correct?. Thanks for your reply .

Comment: The code to grab the bean looks correct to me, you may want to use the class however.  The exception is clearly saying the configuration file cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the application context file onto the classpath, e.g. `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: Is this a permanent fix?  Won't the `WEB-INF/classes` folder get over written with the next build or be not available if deployed?

Comment: Hardly permanent, better to place the file in `src/main/resources` so that the files does end up on the classpath after being built :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe your `applicationContext.xml` file is located on the classpath.  Try placing the file within the root of a `source folder` so that it is placed on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a single bean, you shouldn't need to load the entire application context. In fact, you may not want to because that will load up other things in the context that you don't need. Consider using the Spring "aware" interfaces, such as [BeanFactoryAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryAware.html) or [ApplicationContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html).

Your class that wants a reference to the bean factory or context just implements these, e.g.

```
public class MyClass implements BeanFactoryAware {

    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory factory) {
       // get a reference to the bean factory
    }

    // now in here you can reference the bean factory and lookup the beans

}
```